# My file gets uploaded with my fineuploader setup but yet it shows upload failed. What is the reason for this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, fine-uploader

I'm using fine uploader in a rails application and I've made a gist of what my method and my jQuery script looks like [here](https://gist.github.com/bl4ckdu5t/2e759fcdf13655a8c342)
Here's my console log

[image: ]]

and here's my upload returning failed when it actually didn't fail:

[image]

I thought this was just with my development server where files are being uploaded to FS but I tried it with my staging server that sends the files to a CDN server and it is still successfully uploaded with the same upload failed prompt:

[image]

Comment: Most likely your server is not returning valid JSON. Please include the response headers and response body according to Chrome's developer tools panel (network tab).

Comment: @RayNicholus The uploaded image doesn't appear among files in the network tab

Comment: I looked closely again and it returns what I'd set it to receive from my controller `{"status":true,"id":45}`. My endpoint was a controller method that was configured to handle the upload and I'm returning that on successful upload. It's in the [gistfile](https://gist.github.com/bl4ckdu5t/2e759fcdf13655a8c342) linked in the question

Comment: Most likely your server is not returning valid JSON. Please include the response headers and response body according to Chrome's developer tools panel (network tab).

Comment: https://bpaste.net/show/126a2a08fb6c

Comment: @RayNicholus The link above shows the response header and body

Comment: @RayNicholus can I just have it not give any status message?

Comment: @RayNicholus I think the problem has to do with EXIF data not being properly read and I can't tell why. Could it be that I have to send the uuid with the response from my controller method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not including the mandatory "success" property in your response. It must be set to a value of true to indicate success. This is mentioned in the server documentation at http://docs.fineuploader.com/endpoint_handlers/traditional.html. There is an open case to remove this requirement for newer browsers, scheduled for version 6.0. See https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1325 for specifics.

Comment: You know for a long time I kept thinking I was doing nothing wrong after looking through most of the documentation till I realized I was returning {"status": true} instead of {"success":true}. Thanks