# FineUploader Failing to parse incoming JSON

Tags: json, scala, fine-uploader

I'm using play/scala for a webapp and a scala API, currently running simply on two different ports on localhost:9000 and localhost:8080 respectively.  I have the basic page from the fine-uploader.com website docs, and a simple test page build in Play.  (FWIW, i don't think much of the above is relevant)

When i post a file, chunked or not, Fine uploader receives a 200 from the API and valid JSON, but JSON.parse returns a failure.  The logging from fine-uploader is below.  If i take this output and run it through (in the console)

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json))
```

a valid object is returned.  I can't just `JSON.parse(json)` directly in the browser tools b/c its already an object.  I have checked the types by console.log'ing `typeOf json` in the qq.parseJson method and it returns `string`, so no conversion should be required, though i have tried it with the same results.

fine-uploader console logs:

```
[Fine Uploader 5.5.1] Sending simple upload request for 0 fine-uploader.js:251 
[Fine Uploader 5.5.1] xhr - server response received for 0 fine-uploader.js:251 
[Fine Uploader 5.5.1] responseText = {"code":"UPLOAD_COMPLETE","response":{"MediaModel":{"id":1103,"publicUri":"http://localhost:8080/media/Archive.zip","fileLocation":"/src/services/api/src/main/webapp/media/Archive.zip","mediaDate":{"year":2016,"month":2,"day":28},"mediaOrder":1,"viewName":"","caption":"","altText":"","isPublic":1,"fileSize":1107080,"created":"2016-02-28T14:58:43Z"},"UserMediaModel":{"id":1,"userId":24,"mediaId":3,"created":"2016-02-17T12:48:18Z"}},"errors":[]} fine-uploader.js:251 
[Fine Uploader 5.5.1] Received response status 200 with body: {"code":"UPLOAD_COMPLETE","response":{"MediaModel":{"id":1103,"publicUri":"http://localhost:8080/media/Archive.zip","fileLocation":"/src/services/api/src/main/webapp/media/Archive.zip","mediaDate":{"year":2016,"month":2,"day":28},"mediaOrder":1,"viewName":"","caption":"","altText":"","isPublic":1,"fileSize":1107080,"created":"2016-02-28T14:58:43Z"},"UserMediaModel":{"id":1,"userId":24,"mediaId":3,"created":"2016-02-17T12:48:18Z"}},"errors":[]}  fine-uploader.js:251 
[Fine Uploader 5.5.1] Simple upload request failed for 0
```

The server is responding with a 200 per the API logs and i can see the exact response object in the Response tab of Chrome Dev tools.

I added a custom error handler, but not more more information was provided, just that the error is the text output

```
Error on file number 0 - Archive.zip.  Reason: {"code":"UPLOAD_COMPLETE",....same as above
```

Lastly, all rows are propery inserted into the database as you see from the id's created above.  And all logging points to an equally successful action.

Thanks for any pointers.  I've also put this output in [http://jsonlint.com/](http://JSONLint.com) and it parses fine.

Thanks! (sorry for the lack of JSON formatting, i can change it, but this seemed long enough already)

**EDIT**
It seems that i have satisfied the requirements stated in the other question with `"success":true` and `Content-Type=text/plain`.  The following, per request is the JSON output and the headers

```
Headers: 
Key: Access-Control-Allow-Origin    Value: http://localhost:9000
Key: Date    Value: Mon, 29 Feb 2016 00:55:19 GMT
Key: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    Value: true
Key: Content-Type    Value: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

{
"code": "UPLOAD_COMPLETE",
"response": {
    "MediaModel": {
        "id": 1169,
        "publicUri": "http://localhost:8080/media/Archive.zip",
        "fileLocation": "/src/services/api/src/main/webapp/media/Archive.zip",
        "mediaDate": {
            "year": 2016,
            "month": 2,
            "day": 28
        },
        "mediaOrder": 1,
        "viewName": "",
        "caption": "",
        "altText": "",
        "isPublic": 1,
        "fileSize": 1107080,
        "created": "2016-02-29T00:55:19Z"
    },
    "UserMediaModel": {
        "id": 1,
        "userId": 24,
        "mediaId": 3,
        "created": "2016-02-17T12:48:18Z"
    }
},
"errors": [],
"success": true
}
```

I'm sure this will end up being something silly, so i appreciate the input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My file gets uploaded with my fineuploader setup but yet it shows upload failed. What is the reason for this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990081/my-file-gets-uploaded-with-my-fineuploader-setup-but-yet-it-shows-upload-failed)

Comment: Thanks @RayNicholus - i did notice that in the documentation after and tried it, but to no avail.  Again i tried it with/out chunking.  And ensured that `Content-Type = "text/plain"`  To keep it short, a new paste of the results. http://pastebin.com/knh4VMG4

Comment: Please paste the exact response from your server in the question.

Comment: In your question, you say you have included "status": true in your response, but you've pasted "success": true. Which is it?

Comment: the post is the actual content, i had status on my mind from the linked question and its ultimate fix.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error reported by Fine Uploader, your response is not properly formatted. If you look closely at the response in your browser's network tab (such as with Chrome dev tools), you'll likely see a JSON string that, once parsed using `JSON.parse` results in another JSON string instead of a JavaScript object containing the expected properties. I can't confirm this as you haven't posted the exact response from your server, but I'm certain that this is the case. This is most likely caused by an encoding issue server-side. For example, your server should return this: `{"foo": "bar", "success": true}` instead of this: `"{\"foo\": \"bar\", \"success\": true}"`. I suspect your server is returning the latter.

Comment: Thanks, i'll continue to dig, but what i posted came directly from the Chrome Developer tools and then sent through JSONLint for validation before sending and pretty printing.

Comment: You'll need to look at the response tab in the network section of dev tools. That will give sone insight as to how your server is failing to properly encode the response.

Comment: I appreciate your attention, I've had to move onto other things and as soon as this becomes the priority i'll be back.  But FWIW, all posts have come from the network tab of chrome dev tools.  I log tons of data, but when it comes to debugging issues like this, i stick with what the browser sees.  The first set i posted included the fine uploaded signature, granted without the success...which was my bad.  I'll update the question soon.  Again, thank you for your attention.